# How to build a list of links to html files in Gulp?

Tags: html, npm, gulp

How can you use Gulp to gather in one html file a list of all the pages that are in the directory?

For example, in the build directory I have two files `contact.html` with title **"Contacts"** and `faq.html` with the title **"Frequently asked questions"**, I need to get them and create a `ui.html` which would be a list of links to files of the form:

```html
<a href="faq.html">Frequently asked questions</a>
<a href="contact.html">Contacts</a>
```

Well, with the addition of step your design (a connected css file).

Found the `gulp-listing` module, but it can not be customized, there it is as follows:

```js
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src('./src/*.html')
.pipe(listing('listing.html'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./src/'));
});
```

Comment: Does gulp-listing work for you?  And how do you want to modify its result?

Comment: @Mark works but is slow and there is no option to add your css styles to the resulting page

Answer (score 1):

I used two gulp modules for do this.

1. [gulp-filelist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filelist) - for create file list
2. [gulp-modify-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-modify-file) - for update this file

   ```
   gulp
     .src(['./html/**/*.html'])
     .pipe(require('gulp-filelist')('filelist.js', { relative: true }))
     .pipe(require('gulp-modify-file')((content) => {
        const start = 'var list = '
        return `${start}${content}`
      }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'))
   ```

After run gulp, you got in `js/filelist.js` something like this:

```
 var list = [
   "Cancellation/template.html",
   "Cancellation/email.html",
 ]
```

You can add this script in your html file, and with js display all info.